# Replace numbers by JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript

i have a variable in JavaScript called "something" and it has been assigned with the value of a php variable called  "output" . When i Console.log (something), i get the right output  i.e., 116.076580833333, -33.8541619444444 (string format)  which is the value of "output".

What i want to achieve:
center: [116.076580833333, -33.8541619444444],

Change to

center: [something],

But if i put "something" in the there, my php file gives no output. from what i can see it can only accepts integers. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Javascript

```
var something=<?php echo json_encode($output); ?>;

console.log(something);  // gets the value of $output inside "something"

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({

  

   center: [116.076580833333, -33.8541619444444]  // value of "something" should fill here
  
      
  
});
```

Comment: is "something" an array?

Comment: Okay, let me see if I understand correctly "something is an array" i.e [116.076580833333, -33.8541619444444]. Now, do you want this to be equated to center ? In which case, you should simply write center:something. Or you want the value array of array? Because when you do [something], it implies you want array of arrays

Comment: if i simply write something, i wont get any output. Center only accepts in interger form.

Comment: @jo8080 what is the data type of that javascript variable, like string, integer, array, object?

Comment: No, but what's the data type of something? I'm sorry you should edit the question properly.

Comment: Hey, the data type is integer

Comment: Okay when you console something, what do you get? is it -> [num,num] or "num , num"?

Comment: "num,num" is format i get

Comment: So its a string. Not a number, what @hgb1234 has shared as an answer should work.

Comment: hey, but the value of something is dynamic, ie, i cant put a constant value to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could split by comma and map then cast to number with `Number`

```js
const something = '116.076580833333, -33.8541619444444'
const obj = {
  center: something.split(',').map(Number)
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: But the value of something is inside object php variable

Comment: @jo8080 I saw in the question, you've already `console.log`-ed that. It looks like string value

Comment: yes it is. But the value of something changes time to time depending upon the php variable "output"

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer

JavaScript

```
var something=<?php echo json_encode($output); ?>;
//console.log(something);

const coordinates = something;
const [longitude, latitude] = coordinates.split(',');

console.log(longitude);
console.log(latitude);

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({

  

  center: [longitude, latitude]
      
  
});
```